# static nested class?

Tags: java, классы, static, inner

для чего нужен static nested class? и как его использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вложенные классы — элементы содержащего их класса.
Статические — не имеют доступ к членам внешнего класса. Как и другие поля класса, вложенные классы могут быть объявлены как private, public, protected, или package private.
Для чего использовать вложенные классы
Вот некоторые причины использования вложенных классов:

Это хороший способ группировки классов, которые используются только в одном месте: если класс полезен только для одного другого класса, то логично будет держать их вместе. Вложение таких вспомогательных классов делает код более удобным.
Инкапсуляция: допустим, есть два класса A и B, классу B требуется доступ к свойству класса A, которое может быть приватным. Вложение класса B в класс A решит эту проблему, более того сам класс B можно скрыть от внешнего использования.
Улучшение читаемости и обслуживаемости кода: вложение малых классов в более высокоуровневые классы позволяет хранить код там, где он используется.
Вложенные классы
Как статические переменные и методы, вложенный (статический) класс связан с внешнимклассом. И так же как и статические методы не может напрямую обращаться к полям объекта внешнего класса.

Доступ к вложенному классу осуществляется с помощью следующей конструкции:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass
```

Синтаксис создания объекта вложенного класса:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject = new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

Подробнее можно почитать в этом уроке [Вложенные и внутренние классы в Java. Часть 1](http://easy-code.ru/lesson/java-nested-classes)

Answer (score 3):

Для логической группировки взаимозависимых классов и улучшения инкапсуляции. Например, класс из стандартной библиотеки [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) содержит в себе объявление статического класса [Node](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l278), объекты которого используются для хранения пар ключ-значение.